# Jboss 6 eclipse remote debugging fails for remote session bean injected via JNDI lookup

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jndi, remote-debugging, jboss6.x

I am using JNDI lookups to inject a remote EJB3 session bean inside my spring 3 controller. Since my web module will run in tomcat and the business layer app in a remote Jboss 6, this configuration was decided. For the development I still use only jboss and my web and ear both are deployed in the same jobss instance (jboss 6). Everything works well for me, but when I tried to debug, all the beans injected returns null, so when in debug view, a null pointer exception is thrown when the remote ejb session bean is invoked. Everything works fine in the run mode (non-debug).

I am using eclipse(Helios) and trying remote debugging
I have the jndi.properties file in my jboss/deploy with these settings

`java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces`

any help on this issue...

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since remote debugging did not work for me, I used the jboss plugin for eclipse to make the debug process work.